# testing jwt with factory boy

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, factory-boy

I want to be able to test djang-rest-framework-jwt so i can write some custom custom payload handlers. I am having issue logging in though via `obtain_jwt_token`.

Heres a simple test that should return a 200 status code but I get a 400 error code

> AssertionError: {'non_field_errors': ['Unable to login with provided
>   credentials.']}

I can get it to pass if I use `User.objects.create_user()` and pass in a dict of username and password but would like to use factory boy to be in keeping with the rest of my tests.

factories.py

c

```
lass UserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    username = 'temp'
    email = 'temp@email.com'
    password = 'password'

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, model_class, *args, **kwargs):
        """Override the default ``_create`` with our custom call."""
        manager = cls._get_manager(model_class)

        return manager.create_user(*args, **kwargs)
```

test.py

```
class TestAuthentication:
    def test_jwt(self):
        user = UserFactory()
        request_factory = APIRequestFactory()
        data = {
            'username': user.username,
            'password': user.password
        }

        request = request_factory.post('/', data=data)
        response = obtain_jwt_token(request)

        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK, response.data
```